# How can i sort by viewing text in QTableView?

Tags: qt, sorting, qtableview

i want to sort by not original text but viewing text on QTableView!

How can i sort by viewing text?

original text

```
{cat : 1, dog : 2}
{cat : 2, dog : 3}
```

viewing text

```
1, 2
2, 3
```

i want sort by dog count! (only number)

but current sorting is by its original text

Comment: Do you have one or two columns? If two, sorting the second column by original text (result of `data(1, Qt::DisplayRole)` should give the desired result (or your example isn't complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void QTableView::sortByColumn(int column, Qt::SortOrder order)` can help you to sort all data as your plan.

Comment: i tried that.. but it is sort by original text! my tableview is different display text with original text. because i change viewing text with paint event

Comment: @iamsy Changing the visible text in paint event sounds like a bad idea.